# sql server : Better way to write logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

Please suggest a better way(performance) to write below logic.
Consider I have around 5 similar queries where location id has to be picked up for different areas and store in different columns for further logic.

```sql
SELECT
    @location1 = locid
FROM
    table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.key1 = t2.key2 and t1.flag = 1
WHERE
    t1.area = 'ABC'
```

```sql
SELECT
    @location2 = locid
FROM
    table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.key1 = t2.key2 and t1.flag = 1
WHERE
    t1.area = 'DEF'
```

Comment: Why do you think there is a performance problem, and have you actually measured the performance? If you have good indexes then performance should also be good, but you don't mention what indexes you have.

Comment: It depends what you are doing with `@location1` and `@location2` afterwards

Comment: Do you know all the area values before calling this? 
From where are you calling this and can that handle all locations at once?
What do you mean by *store in different columns for further logic* ?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use conditional aggregation to populate your variables -
However, note that this (well, to be fair, also the queries in the question) assumes that for each `t1.area` there will be only one record in the result set.

```
SELECT @location1 = MAX(CASE WHEN t1.area = 'ABC' THEN locid END)
      ,@location2 = MAX(CASE WHEN t1.area = 'DEF' THEN locid END)
FROM
    table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.key1 = t2.key2 and t1.flag = 1
WHERE
    t1.area IN('ABC', 'DEF')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass all the valid values of Area in a single query and then can store the data in a table variable.

The data can be read using that table variable further as now you only have to query limited dataset to get records.

```
DECLARE @AreaLocationTable     AS TABLE([Location] NVARCHAR(100),Area NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @AreaLocationTable
SELECT
    t1.locid,
        t1.Area
FROM
    table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.key1 = t2.key2 and t1.flag = 1
WHERE
    t1.area in ('ABC','DEF')
```